# Generate new column in pandas dataframe based on conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, polygon, shapely

I have 2 pandas dataframes. The first one contains information about latitude and longitude of station and has only 3 rows:

```
    stat_id    stat_lon     stat_lat
0   db_695203   9.444328    54.787590
1   db_699007   9.438629    54.789577
2   db_695442   9.445865    54.786215
```

The second one contains column 'Polygon' (shapely polygon format) and has 20 rows:

```
0     POLYGON ((9.444721146384639 54.78805404001241,...
1     POLYGON ((9.429828147969117 54.79003403977831,... 
2     POLYGON ((9.429153147576411 54.78516304109078,...
.......................................................
18    POLYGON ((9.417355147148637 54.79108504035977,...
19    POLYGON ((9.44272277037326 54.79218198146992, ...
```

My aim is:

1. to check, whether the point (station with her coordinates) is in polygon (no problem with this)
2. count the number of stations in one polygon (and here is the problem)

What do I do:

```
for j in range(len(piece_clean_data)): #it's a df which contains polygons
P = shapely.wkt.loads(piece_clean_data.iloc[j,87]) #i convert string to Polygon
for i in range(len(three_stations)): #df with 3 stations
    p1 = Point(three_stations.iloc[i,1], three_stations.iloc[i,2]) #station coordinates
    st = P.contains(p1) #the answer is "True/False" - here i check, whether the point is in polygon or not
    if st == 'True': #and here I don't have any idea.
```

So, at the end  I want to have one more column "Number of stations in Polygon", e.g.:

```
    0     POLYGON ((9.444721146384639 54.78805404001241,...   0
    1     POLYGON ((9.429828147969117 54.79003403977831,...   0 
    2     POLYGON ((9.429153147576411 54.78516304109078,...   1
```

Please any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Probably it will be better to use GeoPandas in this case. See [Counting number of points in each grid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/336566/142375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a function that given a row iterates over the station list and counts if the station is contained within the polygon. Then apply this function on each row of the polygon list DataFrame.

```
def num_stations(polygon):
  """Count the number of stations that are within a given polygon."""
  num = 0
  for _, station in three_stations.iterrows():
    p = Point(station['stat_lon'], station['stat_lat'])
    if polygon.contains(p):
      num += 1
  return num

piece_clean_data['station_counts'] = piece_clean_data.apply(num_stations, axis='columns')
```

Comment: thank you! I am not sure whether I can apply this function, because polygons in "piece_clean_data" are strings and they should be converted from strings to polygons first.

Comment: When you use `apply`, pandas simple passes the value in each row to the function you are applying. So in my solution above, the `polygon` parameter will be a string in `num_stations`. You can convert it whatever way you want prior to doing some operation on it.

Comment: it worked! thank you very much! The only thing i had to modify was "axis" parameter - i didn't quite understood why shoud i remove it, but i just removed :)